# Jest mock not covering function or returning error

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying t write a jest mock test for `csvtojson` but I'm getting and error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

api.js:

```
import csv = require('csvtojson')
const request = require('request')

export const getApiData = url => {
  return csv()
   .fromStream(request.get(url)
   .subscribe(json => json)
}
```

api.test.js

```js
import { getApiData } from '../api';
const csv = require('csvtojson');

jest.mock('csvtojson', () => {
  const fromStream = jest.fn();
  const subscribe = jest.fn(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0)));
  const result = { fromStream, subscribe };
  return jest.fn(() => result);
});
jest.mock('request', () => {
  return { get: jest.fn() };
});
describe('getApiData', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    getApiData('http://test.com');
  });
  describe('csv', () => {
    expect(csv).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

then I tested it when if I remove `fromStream` from my `getApiData` function it works, but then my coverage shows that `json => json` has not been called.

I'm really puzzled. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`api.js`:

```js
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const request = require('request');

export const getApiData = url => {
  return csv()
    .fromStream(request.get(url))
    .subscribe(json => json);
};
```

`api.test.js`:

```js
import { getApiData } from './api';
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const request = require('request');

jest.mock('csvtojson', () => {
  const mCsvtojson = {
    fromStream: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    subscribe: jest.fn()
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mCsvtojson);
});
jest.mock('request', () => {
  return { get: jest.fn() };
});

describe('getApiData', () => {
  it('csv', done => {
    const mResponse = { name: 'UT' };
    let observer;
    csv()
      .fromStream()
      .subscribe.mockImplementationOnce(onSuccess => {
        observer = onSuccess;
      });
    request.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(mResponse);
    getApiData('http://test.com');
    const mJSON = {};
    expect(observer(mJSON)).toEqual({});
    expect(request.get).toBeCalledWith('http://test.com');
    expect(csv).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(csv().fromStream).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Object));
    done();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/58842143/api.test.js (10.249s)
  getApiData
    ✓ csv (8ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 api.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.139s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58842143